# ImportError: No module named - Python

Tags: python, import

I have a python application with the following directory structure:

```
src
 |
 +---- main
 |
 +---- util
 |
 +---- gen_py
         |
         +---- lib
```

In the package **main**, I have a python module named **MyServer.py** which has an import statement like:

```
from gen_py.lib import MyService
```

In order for this statement to work, I placed the following line at the beginning of **MyServer.py**:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../gen_py/lib')
```

When I run MyServer.py in the terminal, I get the following error:

> ImportError: No module named gen_py.lib

What I am missing here?

Comment: What was the command line that you used to run MyServer.py? What directory were you in?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Your modification of `sys.path` assumes the current working directory is always in `main/`. This is not the case. Instead, just add the parent directory to `sys.path`:

```
import sys
import os.path

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
import gen_py.lib
```

Don't forget to include a file `__init__.py` in gen_py and lib - otherwise, they won't be recognized as Python modules.

Comment: I have the same problem. I use Windows, Eclipse. What should we do in Eclipse?

Comment: @Ceren This code should work in every IDE. Your IDE (or more precisely, the Python plugin for it) may not actually execute the Python code, in which case you probably need to configure the search path somewhere. Feel free to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about that.

Comment: @phihag Thanks! I had asked a question about an hour ago, feel free to answer it =)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038416/eclipse-pydev-importerror-no-module-named-src-somesrcfile

Comment: Is it possible to put this somewhere not in the my main application?  I used this solution to solve my similar error but now I have a file that looks messy with imports all over the place.  I thought there was a way to do this in the __init__ file but I can't find good examples.

Comment: What does `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))`
 resolve to? Why isn't it `sys.path.append(os.path.join('..', os.path.dirname(__file__)))`?

Comment: @alex `__file__` is the location of the file. Typical values can be `myapp/foo/file.py`, `file.py`, or `/usr/local/share/myapp/foo/file.py`. `os.path.dirname(__file__)` removes the file name from each. Appending `..` gets us into the parent directory. Your proposed code is completely bonkers. For instance, the correct location when running `/usr/local/share/myapp/foo/file.py` from `/home/user/` would be `/usr/local/share/myapp/`. But `os.path.join` will return the second argument if it's an absolute path, so you're getting `/usr/local/share/myapp/foo/`.

Comment: @philhag Oh okay, I thought `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')` would resolve to (for instance) `file.py/..`.  That seemed a little bonkers to me.

Answer (score 6):

For the Python module import to work, you must have "src" in your path, not "gen_py/lib".

When processing an import like `import gen_py.lib`, it looks for a module `gen_py`, then looks for a submodule `lib`.

As the module `gen_py` won't be in "../gen_py/lib" (it'll be in ".."), the path you added will do nothing to help the import process.

Depending on where you're running it from, try adding the relative path to the "src" folder. Perhaps it's `sys.path.append('..')`. You might also have success running the script while inside the src folder directly, via relative paths like `python main/MyServer.py`

Comment: That's not what I said. You don't append gen_py/lib to the path if you're importing "gen_py.lib". You append the folder gen_py is inside, which in this case is probably "..".

Answer (score 5):

```
from ..gen_py.lib import MyService
```

or

```
from main.gen_py.lib import MyService
```

Make sure you have a (at least empty) `__init__.py` file on each directory.

Answer (score 3):

make sure to include `__init__.py`, which makes Python know that those directories containpackages

Answer (score 3):

This is if you are building a package and you are finding error in imports. I learnt it the hard way.The answer isn't to add the package to python path or to do it programatically (what if your module gets installed and your command adds it again?) thats a bad way.

The right thing to do is:
1) Use virtualenv pyvenv-3.4 or something similar
2) Activate the development mode - $python setup.py develop

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if root project directory is coming up in sys.path output.
If not, please add path of root project directory to sys.path.